# Easy way to set multiple class attributes?

Tags: python, class, attributes

For example, if have a 'creature' class:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self,name,hp,damage):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage
```

Now if I want to create an orc, I would do `orc = Creature(0,0,'orc',20,4)`. However, with multiple types of creatures (troll, ogre, etc), this would be impractical: I have to remember the stats for each type of creature, and every time I want to create a creature I have to enter all those different stats.

Is there a way to do this in an easier way? I would for example do `orc = Creature(orc)`, and it would automatically assign its name, hp and damage, which I defined in a different file/part of the code, in a dictionary for example.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I know about inheritance and all the stuff that comes with it, but I read somewhere that making child classes which just set the attributes of the parent to a set value is "not good", although I can't recall the exact reason.

Comment: Inheritance!? Seems like that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: You should read about classes, OOP, inheritance and all this stuff…

Comment: It's "no good" if the set of attributes is fixed, but you inherit solely to fix the values. In your case, different creatures may have different attributes, or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: @StoryTeller I might've explained it wrongly: every creature has the same set of attributes, only the values are different. Your answer with the prototype is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a prototype:

```
proto = {
  "orc" : (200, 300, 0)
  "troll" : (500, 300, 0)
  "wolf" : (100, 100, 0)
  ...
}

class Creature:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = proto[name][0]
        ...
```

The above of course is not complete or safe. But the point is that if you need to create many object of the same "type" just keep the default values aside someplace else.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! It's also nicely compact. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to use [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

You should really read some tutorial on OOP *before* writing a game in an object-oriented language.

Comment: I know about inheritance (I'm not _that_ inexperienced :P), but I read somewhere that making child classes that just set the attributes to set values is 'bad'. I forgot the exact reason, but it seemed pretty logical at that time.

Comment: @Lokkij That can't be true. _Orc_ is obviously a different _Creature_ even if some stats is the only difference and inheritance here is the right thing to do.